# Yes No in Prolog if not (yes/no) then display invalid command(input)

Tags: prolog

I am creating an Expert System for Cell Phone Repair.

The answers must be just [yes or no], anything else will display "invalid input."
How can i trap that in my code?

```
ask(Question) :-  write('Question: '),
      write(Question),
      write('? '),
      write('(yes or no) : '),
      read(Response),
      nl,
      ((Response == yes ; Response == y) -> assert(yes(Question)) ; 
       (Response==no ; Response ==n) -> assert(no(Question)) ;
        write('\nInvalid Input!!!\n'),fail).
```

I still can't implement what I want to display if any wrong spelling is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... Your code definitely works. Just be sure to change `assert` with `asserta` or `assertz`if you use gprolog.

```
| ?- [expert].
compiling *** for byte code...
*** compiled, 7 lines read - 2111 bytes written, 14 ms
(1 ms) yes
| ?- ask(man).
Question: man? (yes or no): y.
yes
| ?- ask(woman).
Question: woman? (yes or no): no.
(1 ms) yes
| ?- ask(silly).
Question: silly? (yes or no): dunno.
Invalid Input!!!
no
| ?- yes(man).
yes
| ?- no(man).
no
| ?- yes(woman).
no
| ?- no(woman).
(1 ms) yes
```

Comment: Thanks...what is gprolog?because i am using amzi listener to run my program.. is there a way to automaticaly run my program just like you are when you click an application and it will run directly..without using a listener?... i heard about .xml when you compile in amzi but i dont know tlhow to do it... help me please... tnx Aurélien...

Comment: `gprolog`stands for [GNU prolog](http://www.gprolog.org). The interpreter can be run with [options for consulting a file and executing a clause](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc6).

Comment: i tried it in Amzi but still it does not work... can anybody give me  another option on how to do it.. just to have that output...